# Grover search with zero error

Tags: grovers-algorithm

Suppose we need to find out whether or not a set of elements $x_1,...,x_n$ contains any  marked items.Show that any quantum algorithm that can solve this problem successfully with  zero probability error requires  $Ω(n)$ queries to the elements.

I know it is quantum search algorithm, with high probability it is known to have $Ω(\sqrt{n})$ queries, however I don't know how to prove the lower bound when it needs zero error.